# How do I handle an empty table with rhandsontable in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

When the last row in my rhandsondtable is deleted I get the following error:

```
Warning: Error in matrix: 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
Stack trace (innermost first):
    61: matrix
    60: <Anonymous>
    59: do.call
    58: hot_to_r
    57: observerFunc [#64]
    2: runApp
    1: editTable [#126]
```

Same thing happens when I run the code in [this blog post](http://stla.github.io/stlapblog/posts/shiny_editTable.html). I'm using this code to experiment.

I want to be able to prevent this. I'm open to different options, e.g.

- Determine if the HOT has no rows and display an "Add row" button instead of the table
- Prevent deletion of the last row

I've tried using the `minSpareRows` option, but this results in the following error

```
Warning: Error in row.names<-.data.frame: invalid 'row.names' length
Stack trace (innermost first):
    63: row.names<-.data.frame
    62: row.names<-
    61: rownames<-
    60: <Anonymous>
    59: do.call
    58: hot_to_r
    57: observerFunc [#64]
    2: runApp
    1: editTable [#127]
```

I don't now hot to check if the `input$hot` has rows in it and, as the `hot_to_r` function is the one failing, I can't use the data frame to do it.

Any help on how to deal with my "empty" table problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input$hot` is a list that contains three items, with the first item `input$hot$data` containing the table data. So you can check `length(input$hot$data)` to determine how many rows remain.

Comment: Thanks. Discovered this independently so know it works. :)